# ModX Revo pdoMenu настройка меню на сайта

Tags: html5, cms, modx, revo

Добрый день, снова небольшой вопрос по modx. Установленный плагин pdoTools
Пытаюсь сделать вот такую навигацию на сайте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Составил вот такой скрипт в чанке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[[pdoMenu?
    &level=`1`
    &parents=`17`
    &displayStart=`1`
    &hereClass=`cat_active`
    &lastClass=`0`
    &firstClass=`0`
    &outerClass=`gallery_category`
    &tplOuter=`@INLINE <ul class="gallery_category">[[+wrapper]]</ul>`
    &tpl=`@INLINE <a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]><li[[+classes]]>[[+menutitle]]</li>[[+wrapper]]</a>`
]]
```

Но все это выводится следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните пожалуйста, почему элементы меню выводятся как h2 элементы? Я же явно прописываю

```
&tpl=`@INLINE <a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]><li[[+classes]]>[[+menutitle]]</li>[[+wrapper]]</a>
```

А вместо этого он выводит ..

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Может из-за того что рушится список. Попробуйте:

```
&tpl=`@INLINE <li[[+classes]]><a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогает

Answer (score 0):

```
&tplStart   Чанк оформления корневого пункта, при условии, что включен &displayStart. По умолчанию: @INLINE <h2[[+classes]]>[[+menutitle]]</h2>[[+wrapper]]
```